# "Cannot connect to target site" issue with visual studio

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

How to fix this issue when trying to create SharePoint project in Visual studio
[image]

Comment: Do you have SharePoint running on the machine where VS is installed?

Comment: Yes and its get connected the testing server successfully which is installed in the current machine and when trying to connect my production site this error occurred.

Comment: Right, and the production site I am assuming is not on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: So that is your answer right there.  You will not be able to connect from VS on one machine to SP on a different machine.  If you are trying to deploy a finished project, you will have to package either a Farm or Sandbox solution in order to deploy to the production environment.

Comment: You mean build the finished project and deploy wsp manually to the production site?

Comment: Yes, exactly, build a WSP and deploy WSP manually (or with Powrshell) to the production site.